# Procedure help pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql

Create a procedure, LE_P6 that accepts a single numeric input parameter p_deptno representing a department number, sums the salaries of all employees fro that particular department, and then outputs that information to the screen. To handle the case where an inputted p_deptno does not exist, test if the um is null. If the sum is null, raise a user-defined exception and output to the screen a message indicating an error has occurred. In addition, test the procedure using the following cases and include the output.

p_deptno is 10

p_deptno is 50

```
set serveroutput on
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LE_P6 (
  p_deptno dept.deptno%TYPE,
  p_sal emp.sal%TYPE) IS
  null_salary EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(null_salary, -20101);
BEGIN
  select SUM(SAL) 
  Into p_sal
  from emp;
EXCEPTION
WHEN null_salary THEN
  DBMS.OUTPUT_PUT.LINE ('Salary cannot be null');
End LE_P6;
```

Comment: What is your question? You described what procedure should do and posted a code. What do you expect? What is wrong with your code?

Comment: 1. You are selecting the sum of all employees, not only of those of p_deptno. 2. You are defining an exeption but never throw it. Do you expect the DBMS to guess that this exception shall be thrown in case the sum is null? How? 3. The query looks just fine. I see no reason for it to cause an exception, so the exception block is never used.

Comment: I need this to select the sum of only employees from a specific department number (p_deptno). As a newbie, I'm not really sure how to throw the exception. Do I use the RAISE command? The exception is only for when the sum returns a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one parameter not two and you have a typo in `DBMS_OUTPUT` package name. Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LE_P6 (
  p_deptno dept.deptno%TYPE) IS
  null_salary EXCEPTION;
  p_sal number;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(null_salary, -20101);
BEGIN
  select SUM(SAL) 
  Into p_sal
  from emp
  where deptno = p_deptno;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (p_sal);
EXCEPTION
WHEN null_salary THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Salary cannot be null');
End LE_P6;
```

Comment: This compiled cleanly. I see what you're saying about the parameters now. And yes, that was an obvious typo I should have caught. Going to Execute and then probably give you the "check mark" for accepted answer.

Comment: Each department returns the value of: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

29025
Department 10 should be 8,750 and 50 does not exist therefore calling my exception.

Comment: because there is missing `where deptno = p_deptno`. Try now. @DerekPike

Comment: Thanks @Kacper. That fixed 10, but my exception still isn't working. I'm going to take a closer look to see if I can figure it out on my own. I really do appreciate the help and the quick responses. I'll be in touch if I can't get it figured out though.

Comment: Small hint. You need to `raise` exception. You defined it properly but when you execute query for non existing department you get result as `null`. Before first `DBMS_OUTPUT` you need to `raise` your defined exception `if(p_sal is null)`. Good luck @DerekPike

Comment: Thanks I fixed it with....                                                                                    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LE_P6 (
  p_deptno dept.deptno%TYPE) IS
  null_salary EXCEPTION;
  p_sal number;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(null_salary, -20101);
BEGIN
  select SUM(SAL) 
  Into p_sal
  from emp
  where deptno = p_deptno;
  if p_sal is null then
  Raise null_salary;
  else
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (p_sal);
  end if;
EXCEPTION
WHEN null_salary THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Salary cannot be null');
End LE_P6;

Comment: Easier to read this way. Put this in my BEGIN statement....                 if p_sal is null then
  Raise null_salary;
  else
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (p_sal);
  end if;

Comment: I hinted at the raise statement in the comments above.